# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS: "ubuntu-security-status" states "0 receive package updates with LTS". do I have to worry?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, security

Something's probably broken.  On my machine I see this:

```
# ubuntu-security-status 
2131 packages installed, of which:
   0 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
2131 packages are from third parties

Packages from third parties are not provided by the official Ubuntu
archive, for example packages from Personal Package Archives in
Launchpad.
For more information on the packages, run 'ubuntu-security-status
--thirdparty'.

This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Advantage subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

What's broken?  What causes `ubuntu-security-status` to tell `0 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025`?

### Notes

- A second machine which once was 12.04 and is updated all along to 20.04.1 now shows a comparable output.
- I use an apt-cache which is shown as `192.168.XX.XX:3142` below.
- `ddebs` are needed [for `stap`](https://github.com/hilbix/tino/blob/master/howto/stap.md#fsyncstp) to function
- `/etc/apt/sources.list` is 0 bytes as everything is managed below `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
- The system was initially installed as 20.04 and now is 20.04.1

Some more info about my machine:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ uname -a
Linux XXXX 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# apt update && apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal InRelease        
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Get:4 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal Release [1838 B]
Hit:5 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:10 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com focal InRelease
Ign:11 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates InRelease
Ign:12 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-proposed InRelease
Hit:13 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release
Hit:15 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release
Hit:17 http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-proposed Release
Fetched 1838 B in 3s (551 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: 20.04.1 is scheduled for release tomorrow.  How did that happen?

Comment: What package is `ubuntu-security-status` in?

Comment: @OrganicMarble `dpkg -S $(which ubuntu-security-status)` gives `update-manager-core: /usr/bin/ubuntu-security-status`

Comment: @Tino does not exist on my 18.04 system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of that program tests package sources to see if they are from archive.canonical.com. If not, they are assumed to be third party.

Test for yourself by changing your apt source from it's current URL to archive.canonical.com. Then run ubuntu-security-status again. It should work properly.

This is arguably a bug, since folks using some legitimate mirrors and apt-proxies will get spurious results. It's a Python 3 script (/usr/bin/ubuntu-security-status), so anybody is welcome to follow the logic and code up a solution to contribute.

Comment: I leave this as the accepted answer because it pointered me [in the correct direction](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266780/164798).

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of the reader, thanks to [user535733's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264844/164798) I found how to fix this problem without changing the Ubuntu script.

`/usr/bin/ubuntu-security-status` recognizes `$MY_MIRROR` variable to supply additional official mirrors.  With only a little tweak, this variable can be automatically populated.  Like this:

```
MY_MIRROR="$(sed -n '/^#MIRROR#//p' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.conf)" /usr/bin/ubuntu-security-status
```

All you need is to add lines of the form

```
#MIRROR# URL
```

to your files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to hint this hack.

Example run:

```
# grep '^#MIRROR#' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/20.04.list:#MIRROR# http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/20.04.list:#MIRROR# http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/20.04.list:#MIRROR# http://192.168.XX.XX:3142/ddebs.ubuntu.com
#
# MY_MIRROR="$(sed -n 's/^#MIRROR#//p' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list)" 
2412 packages installed, of which:
1835 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
 574 could receive security updates with ESM Apps until 4/2030
   3 packages are from third parties

Packages from third parties are not provided by the official Ubuntu
archive, for example packages from Personal Package Archives in
Launchpad.
For more information on the packages, run 'ubuntu-security-status
--thirdparty'.

Enable Extended Security Maintenance (ESM Apps) to get 2 security
updates (so far) and enable coverage of 574 packages.

This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Advantage subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage

#
```

I will add this solution [to my update script](https://github.com/hilbix/tino/blob/master/howto/.apt) soon.